# Base 64 encoded image in email

Tags: email, encoding, outlook, base64

I'm trying to send an email programatically that has the images embedded, to eliminate dependency on access to our network, or hosting files externally (corporate security red tape etc. etc.)

I was able to do this by encoding the image to base 64. However, I'm having issues with specific clients. Most importantly, in Outlook, the image shows as a broken link. The same thing is happening in Windows (10) mail. The images render in several other clients (Blue Mail for Android, a non-stock iPhone client and the web based client for my ISP).

On a side it looks like Outlook is replacing "+" signs in the base64 to `&#43;` , although I'm not sure if that's related or not. I can save the source of the outlook email (even with the `&#43;` ) as an html file and view it in a browser fine.

I have tried encoding using different characters here  : https://cryptii.com/pipes/hex-to-base64

...to avoid having "+" signs. None of the other variants worked, and in fact, they all broke the images in the other clients.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the answer you got doesn't solve this completely, please [edit] your question to include *(a)* a sample of a problematic message (ideally trimmed down to the bare essentials) and *(b)* the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook (or rather Word, which renders HTML messages in Outlook), does not support embedded base64 encoded images. You would need to add image attachments, set their `Content-id` MIME header, and refer to images like that through the `cid` attribute (`<img src="cid:xyz">`)